# Error from Jenkins when a tooltip is on a dot highchart

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, highcharts

I have a graphic like this: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-bands

and I'm having a problem when I try to get the info inside of every dot. My tooltip is on the dot and Selenium doesn't recognize the dot and returns error:

```
"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (422.01666259765625, 429.73333740234375). Other element would receive the click: <rect height="450" width="540" y="0" x="0" fill="#FFFFFF" ry="5" rx="5"></rect> (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"
```

The case is the following:

[image]

I get the dot info this way:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(dot));
    // action class to click dot
    Actions action = new Actions((WebDriver) driver);
    action.click(element).build().perform(); 
   // get info;
   String toolTipText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(tooltip)).getText();
```

Any idea how could I solve this problem? 
You have to know that this is happening only using a Jenkins server. From my local computer, I don't get this error.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what the problem is... you are trying to click an element that is covered by another element (another element would receive the click). You need to dismiss or otherwise get rid of the tooltip (click elsewhere, etc.) before you attempt to click the dot.

The most likely reason you aren't seeing it on your machine but are on the Jenkins box is that the screen resolution is not the same on the two machines.

Comment: I stated it in the answer, `You need to dismiss or otherwise get rid of the tooltip (click elsewhere, etc.) before you attempt to click the dot.`

Comment: I understand you, but I tried to click elsewhere and then click on the dot, but it doesn't solve the problem. The tooltip is on the dot equally.

Comment: Please post a link to the page or at least some sample page that shows the same behavior.

Comment: I can't post a link or similar page page because it's necessary to login. Only I can show you is the image below...

Comment: You provided a link on highcharts.com. Surely you can find a sample there or elsewhere that exhibits the same issue that your chart does. The problem is that you need to close the tooltip. We can't tell you how to do that without a specific example.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I can't find an exact example of my error in another web page. Maybe the cause is a problem with my web... I don't know... but the solution that you say "to close the tooltip" I don't understand why you say that because I need the tooltip to get the info from it...

Comment: The error you posted is because you are trying to click something behind the popup. In order to successfully click, you need to close or otherwise remove the popup after you get the text from it.